# Bootstrap 5 Accordion - easy way to move icons

Tags: css

Really need to make an accordion with icons in the left corner, not the right:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30Q4l.png)

Can i do it in pure CSS Bootstrap5, no JS?

```
.accordion2-button:not(.collapsed)::after {
    background-image: url("./icons/plus.svg");
    box-shadow: none;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.accordion2-button::after {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 1rem;
    height: 1rem;
    margin-left: auto;
    content: "";
    background-image: url("./icons/plus.svg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 1rem;
    box-shadow: none;
    transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

HTML here:

```
<p>
<a class="btn custom accordion2-button collapsed text-btns" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#multiCollapseExample1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample1">
Text</a>
 </p>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :) Adding details of html and other parts of css in a stack snippet would help.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: So move your icon after text in HTML

Comment: i added HTML here, but don't understand how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Make
`<span class="icon2 collapsed"></span>`

before text - and copy all properties of accordion2-button to new class icon2